# How to set the NFC scan cycle time in Android

Tags: android

If it is possible to set (or change) the NFC scan cycle time ? We had some experiments to detect different smart phones with NFC embedded, and found there is variety of scan cycle time, it seems depends on phone manufacturers. Some phones scan NFC tag once every 300~400 min seconds and some time span is 700~800 min seconds.

I wonder if Android provides a function for the scan time setting ? Or any method can do the similar functions ? Tks.